# Generic WithEvents

Tags: .net, vb.net

Error:

> **'WithEvents'** variables can only be
>   typed as ***classes, interfaces or type
>   parameters with class constraints***

Background:

```
Public Class Tadpole(Of T As IVisibleChanged, P As IVisibleChanged)
  Private WithEvents _Tad As T ' ERROR '
  Private WithEvents _Pole As P ' ERROR '

  Public Property Tad() As T ...

  Public Property Pole() As P ...

End Class

''' IVisibleChanged '''
Public Interface IVisibleChanged
  Property Visible() As Boolean
  Event VisibleChanged As EventHandler
End Interface
```

Workaround:

a. Use `AddHandler` to handle events defined in a structure.

EDIT

b. use `Private WithEvents _Tad As`**`IVisibleChanged`** (M.A. Hanin)

c. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is because WithEvents cannot support value types. When you only constrain T to be IVisibleChanged you are not guaranteeing a reference type so WithEvents cannot be used. I don't know the VB syntax but if it's anything like C# you could probably do:

```
' Not sure of the VB syntax.
(Of T As {IVisibleChanged, Class})
```

This guarantees that T will not only implement IVisibleChanged by also that it won't be a struct.