# Where does the WinForms Designer read information for event handlers? Present in code but missing in designer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have not found any solution for this issue. I have a WinForms application that is under development in Visual Studio 2017.

- Event handlers are not showing up in the WinForm Designer.
- Event handlers are present in the code and work. So this is not an immediate show stopper.
- Event handlers were added through the WinForms Designer. I then went to the source code and fleshed out the body of the event handlers.
- However, they do not appear in the Windows Form Designer list of events.

```
Region "Event Handlers"

    Private Sub OnCellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles RosterDataGrid.CellValueChanged

        Dim changedRow As DataRow = _excelRoster.RosterDataSet.Tables(0).Rows().Item(e.RowIndex)

        changedRow.Item(1) = "Updated"
        _rosterControl.Updated = _rosterControl.Updated + 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub OnRowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles RosterDataGrid.RowsAdded

        MsgBox("Row Added")

    End Sub

#End Region
```

- But do not show up in the Windows Form Designer. Note that `OnCellValueChanged`  that handles `CellValueChanged` does not show up at all in the Events property of the Windows Form Designer.

[image]

In the image above, the events for the selected `DataGridView` are not present in the Windows Form Designer.

[image]

The image above shows the result of the `OnCellValueChanged` event handler firing. The `Change Type` column is stamped with "Updated" and the `Updated` count for Aetna is set to 1.

The image below shows the `OnRowsAdded` event firing. There is no entry shown in the Windows Form Designer for the `RowsAdded` event for this `DataGridView`.

[image]

This could be an impediment to other developers who may need to work on this code in the future. Problems like this are indicative that something is fundamentally wrong and could lead to serious problems.

- Control Property settings **are** showing up.
- I am using the version 15.9.55 of Visual Studio 2017
- Additionally, the "**Report a Problem**" item in Visual Studio 2017 is not working.

### How I am adding event handlers

Below, I am adding an event handler for the `RowsRemoved` event of my `DataGridView` control.

1. In the Windows Form Designer, I locate the `RowsRemoved` event and enter `OnRowsRemoved`.
   [image]
2. This adds the following code.

```
    Private Sub OnRowsRemoved(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs) Handles RosterDataGrid.RowsRemoved

    End Sub
```

Note that the text `OnRowsRemoved` does not exist in the `InitializeComponent` method in the `Designer` code. No `AddHandler` was added to `InitializeComponent`.

3. When I switch back to the Windows Form Designer, there is no entry for the `RowsRemoved` event.

[image]

### What I have tried thus far

- Repair from the Visual Studio Installer. This does not fix this issue.
- "Report a Problem" in Visual Studio 2017 does not work. So I could not Report the Problem.
- Cleared the Visual Studio 2017 cache by:

> 1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
> 2. Delete the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\ComponentModelCache` directory.
> 3. Restart Visual Studio.

> Note: *There is no option to `Clear the Cache` under the `More` button in the `Visual Studio Installer`.*

### Questions

- Where does the WinForms designer obtain information on event handlers for controls?
- The event handlers are present in code and work.

> I do not see any event handlers in the `Designer` code file at all. This is the reason for the question on where designer is looking for handlers.

### Notes

1. The Windows Form Designer adds a `Friend WithEvents` declaration to the `Designer` source - so individual event handlers are not added to the `Designer` source control. See [stackoverflow.com/a/44265658/10024425](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44265658/10024425) as per
   Tu deschizi eu inchid in the comments below.

Comment: You didn't provide any information. Where *did* you set the event handlers and how? What does `Event handlers are present in the code` mean, where? The designer works fine. If there was such a basic problem millions of developers would have noticed 21 years ago. There wouldn't even be a Visual Studio now if the designer didn't work. WinForms and WebForms and their designers were the most important features of Visual Studio

Comment: Where are all those quotes from? If they're your own comments, don't format them as quote. Unless they help describe the problem, don't include them at all.

Comment: As for where the designer saves *everything*, it's in the `.Designer.cs` partial file, in the `InitializeComponents` method. Everything done on the designer modifies the contents of that method. When you load a form, that method actually gets executed to create all components. When you add an event in the designer, it adds the method to your codebehind file and then registers that method as an event handler in `InitializeComponents`.

Comment: See my edits above.  The screenshots show that the event handlers are not shown in the Windows Form Designer yet the code for the event handlers is being called. This is a potential issue for any developers who need to maintain the code in the future.

Comment: Where do you create the event handlers? Naming a method `OnCellValueChanged` doesn't make it an event handler. VB can register event handlers by name, if the method follows the `ComponentName_EventName` convention. `Oxxx` are the virtual methods that raise the events, not the event handlers

Comment: For example, in the [Textbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) class, `OnTextAlignChanged` is the method that raises the `TextAlignChanged` event. If you create your own component that inherits from `TextBox` you could override `OnTextAlignChanged` to handle the event in the component itself before raising it to subscribers. For other componets to handle that event though, they'd have to subscribe to `TextBox.TextAlignChanged`, either by calling `AddHanlder` or using `+=` notation

Comment: If you double-clicked on the `TextAlignChanged` of `MyTextBox` in the designer, the designer would generate `MyTextBox_TextAlignChanged` in your code-behind and add `.AddHandler` in `InitializeComponents` in `MyForm.Designer.vb`. You could add a handler yourself without the designer if you used `.AddHandler` or `.TextChanged += MyHandler` *after* the call to `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: See the additional section on how I am adding event handlers above. There is no AddHandler call added in InitialzeComponents.

Comment: I have used the designer in the past - for years - without this issue.  I'm looking for the `AddHandler` and not finding it. When I do a `Find In Files` for the newly added `OnRowsRemoved`, I only find the event handler added by the WinForms Designer.

Comment: You didn't poste any event handlers. `OnCellValueChanged` and any `OnXXX` methods are *not* event handlers

Comment: Scroll to the right in the code above. You will see the `Handles ...`.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44265658/10024425

Comment: The event handler registration is done by the `Handles` clause in the method declaration.

Comment: I have added the link from  Tu deschizi eu inchid to the text above. Very useful.  On the `Handles` clause, my methods all have a `Handles` clause, however, they are not being picked up by the Windows Forms Designer.  Are there special rules or locations where the designers must reside to be recognized?

Comment: The issue that you're facing isn't clear. Are you new to VB.NET? If so, the very end of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76416772/10024425) may contain some useful information.

Comment: Does this only happen in the current project or does it happen in a new project too? Is there any possibility of upgrading to a newer version of VS? I don't recall having had this issue in VS 2017 but I don't have it installed to test now. If it's all projects and VS is having other issues, maybe a repair of VS is in order. That said, I'm not sure whether VS 2017 is still under support so, if not, that might explain the report option not working.

Comment: I am not new to VB.NET. I have used it extensively for more than 15 years. I have also used C#, F# and some Q#. Put simply, event handlers for controls that are present in the code-behind of a form do not appear in the Visual Studio 2017 Windows Form Designer. The events do fire.   In the last image in the body of this post, the event handlers are not listed (see lower-right hand corner of image). Event handlers added through the Designer are written to the code-behind but not shown in the Form Designer Events list. This will be confusing for anyone who needs to maintain the code in the future

Comment: The article [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) has some instructions how one can report a problem from _Visual Studio Installer_ rather than from _Visual Studio_. However, the first thing they are probably going to ask you to do is to [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).